# URL with hash in Spring Mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

everyone.

I'm using Spring MVC 4. My App sends activation url to user's email.

Activation url:

```
www.example.com:8080/myapp/user/activate/$2a$10$Ax2WL93zU3mqjtdxuYlYvuWWyQsPBhkhIfzYHJYk4rdNlAY8qCyC6
```

But, my App can't find path.

My controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/activate/{hash})
public void activateUser(@PathVariable("hash") String hash) {
    userService.activate(hash);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

I've found out that if hash contains dot (".") then throws 404 error.

I've change my url:

```
www.example.com:8080/myapp/user/activate?code=$2a$10$Ax2WL93zU3mqjtdxuYlYvuWWyQsPBhkhIfzYHJYk4rdNlAY8qCyC6
```

and my controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/user/activate)
public void activateUser(@RequestParam("code") String hash) {
    userService.activate(hash);
}
```

It works perfectly.

Comment: whats the error, and log ?

Comment: There's 404 Exception. I can attach log later.

Comment: have you got any request mappings working?

Comment: Yes, I have. If I send as hash an Integer value, it works.

Comment: This is weird... I tried the same thing in one of my controllers and it worked perfectly

Comment: Is you application context path "/"?

Comment: No, it isn't. There is like this www.example.com:8080/myapp/user/activate/{hash}

Comment: So if you call it with the application context in your URI as well, did you verify with the debugger that it won't run the controller? I'm asking, cause you return void. I tried this here as well and got a 404, but the controller was called.

Answer (score 3):

you are not returning anything from the controller, hence receiving a 404

Comment: I've returned "redirect:/user" and it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @Nim Good catch! I initially checked for the same thing, but since I was using the debugger and saw that the method was being called, I don't look any further!

Answer (score 0):

If you have dot (.) in your path variable value, then you must declare it explicitly in the RequestMapping, as shown below -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/download/{attachmentUri:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadAttachment(@PathVariable("attachmentUri") String attachmentUri,
                                                              HttpServletResponse response,
                                                              WebRequest webRequest) {

}
```